# How do I reset the state to its initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I can't seem to reset the default state; how do I do that? I tried this but all it does is add `state` to state and calls it undefined.

```
const initialState = {
  name: null,
  coins: 0,
  image: null,
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_GROUP_COINS:
      return {
        ...state,
        coins: state.coins + action.coins
      };
    case types.DELETE_GROUP:
      return {
        state: undefined
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `case types.DELETE_GROUP:
      return initialState;` not work, or is that not what you intended?

Comment: That would give me `state:{state: {initialState}}` instead. Because it assigns it to `state` inside `state`

Comment: I don't think it would - `return { state: initialState }` would do that - `return initialState` should work as expected.

Comment: Oh wait sorry I read it wrong my bad. I will try it thanks that seems to make sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reset the state to the `initialState`, simply `return initialState`, like this:

```
case types.DELETE_GROUP:
  return initialState;
```

Remember that in the reducer, the object that you return **is the new state**. You don't need to wrap it in another object, like this:

```
return {
    state: ...
}
```

That will give you a property called `state` in your state, which isn't at all what you need.

[From the documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions):

> The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and **returns the next state.**

It's easy to get confused about this, so be careful! Take a look at your `default` case if you're still not quite sure: you're returning the old `state` variable as the new state, **not** `{ state: state }` which you are essentially doing with the current `DELETE_GROUP` handler.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Works like a charm